# How do I break lines in a multirow setup (and column names)?

Tags: tables, columns

I was trying both break lines in the cells of my first column and in some column titles. I've tried the suggestion of using `\pbox`. But it does not seem to work. I've looked already for some answers and I understand this might be interpreted as a duplicate -- but bear with me, it is really not working. Here is an example of the code that I've been working with:

*Observation: I've been trying to do this table in the beamer type of document. One of the answers, though being really helpful, does not work with that type of document -- so I will make it explicit in the code right now. Also, I've have corrected the name of the columns, which weren't in the right order.*

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}
\begin{document}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Table 1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Company}} & \textbf{Temperature} & \textbf{Observations} & \textbf{\pbox{2cm}{Temperature Test\\on Hot Water}} & \textbf{Temperature Test on Cold Water} & \textbf{Consistency} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\pbox{2cm}{Product \\ 1}} & Company 1 & 13.5 & 84 & 1000.5 & 1000.7 & 1000.8 \bigstrut\\
        \cline{2-7}     & Company 2 & 14.3 & 71 & 1000.2 & 1000.9 & 1000.12 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
end{document}
```

Comment: Entries in columns marked as `l`, `c` or `r` will never break on its own. You'll have to do this manually, or use an alternative column specification (like `p{<len>}`).

Comment: If I were to use `\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}}` it would break after 2cm?

Comment: Correct... Depending on whether hyphenation is possible after 2cm, or a break in general.

Comment: You can break lines inside multirow if you remove `*` and use `\multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\centering Product \\ 1}`

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain what you wnat very simply with the `makecell`, which allows form line breaks in cells  with the `makecell`, `\multirowcell`, `\thead` and `\multirowhead`. The `bigstrut` command is replaced with the `\makegapedcells` switch, after we've defined the value of cell gapes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, pbox, bigstrut}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\begin{document}

\noindent
{\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
  \hline
  \thead{Product} & \thead{Temperature} & \thead{Date} & \thead{Observations} & \thead{Temperature Test \\on Hot Water} & \thead{Temperature Test \\on Cold Water} & \thead{Consistency} \\
  \hline
  \multirowcell{2}[-5pt]{Product\\ 1} & Company 1 & 13.5 & 84 & 1000.5 & 1000.7 1000.8 & \\
  \cline{2-7} & Company 2 & 14.3 & 71 & 1000.2 & 1000.9 & 1000.12 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}%

\end{document}
```

For a `beamer` document, you can use the `\rothead` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow,rotating}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lb}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\renewcommand\cellrotangle{40}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1cm}
{\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\makegapedcells
  \setlength{\rotheadsize}{1cm}\footnotesize\centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \rothead{ \\\rlap{Product}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rothead{\\\rlap{Temperature}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rothead{\\ Date}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \rothead{\\\rlap{Observations}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rothead{\rlap{TemperatureTest}\\ \rlap{on Hot Water}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rothead{\rlap{Temperature Test}\\\rlap{on Cold Water}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rothead{\\\rlap{Consistency}}} \\[-0.5ex]
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{Product \\ 1} & Company 1 & 13.5 & 84 & 1000.5 & \makecell{1000.7\\ 1000.8} & \\
    \cline{2-7} & Company 2 & 14.3 & 71 & 1000.2 & 1000.9 & 1000.12 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: But is it possible to use these environments in a beamer document? I think I tried your code correctly and while beamer, for some reason, it does not work.

Comment: I introduced it only because your table is too wide for a normal document. It also seems to be a little too wide for beamer. Perhaps use a smaller fontsize, or rotate column heads (there's a `\rothead` command in `makecell`)?

Comment: So I would use `\rothead` instead of `\thead` then?

Comment: As I said you have two solutions: reduce font size (which may be problematic for slides) or have rotated column heads. Or split into two tables, if it is sensible.

Comment: @John Doe: I added a demo of what can be done with `beamer` and `\rothead`.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the line 16 of your code. "!Extra alignment has been changed...". I cannot copy the full error. I don't know if there is something that I'm changing when I copy and paste it.

Comment: In the new or the first code?

Comment: In the new code. The one made for the beamer document class.

Comment: It was a problem with my editor that added lots of spurious `&`. The code is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what package \pbox comes from, but \parbox works just fine if you make it wide enough to contain "Temperature".  OTOH, I couldn't get \bigstrut to do anything on the top row, so I used \fbox instead.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}
\begin{document}
\fboxrule=0pt
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Temperature} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Observations} 
    & \fbox{\parbox{2.2cm}{\centering\textbf{Temperature Test on Hot Water}}}
    & \fbox{\parbox{2.2cm}{\centering\textbf{Temperature Test on Cold Water}}} & \textbf{Consistency} \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Product\\1}} & Company 1 & 13.5 & 84 & 1000.5 & 1000.7 1000.8 \bigstrut \\
    \cline{2-7}     & Company 2 & 14.3 & 71   & 1000.2 & 1000.9 & 1000.12 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{document
```

}